# Ajax not working if the URL has www

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I have jquery code that posts to a page in codeigniter 
my base url is like

```
http://example.com
```

if the user access my site like this example.com this works but if user acces
my site like `www.example.com`then ajax does not work.
my jquery code is:

```
$.post( "<?php echo base_url();?>home/latestnew", {  page: page })
        .done(function( data ) {
            $("#pag_data").html( data );
    });
```

any simple trick to make it work for both scenarios thanks.

Comment: how about not including the `base_url()`?

Comment: You need not to include `echo base_url()` since the file path remains unchanged though you move file from server to server.

Comment: are you sure about the problem??

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju yes i am sure about the problem.

Comment: thanks everyone my problem is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no big issue. In `config/config.php` keep empty `base_url`:

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
```

Note that Codeigniter loads `base_url` automatically.

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this...

```
$.post( "<?php echo str_replace('www.', '', base_url());?>+home/latestnew", {  page: page })
        .done(function( data ) {
            $("#pag_data").html( data );
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.post( "<?php echo base_url();?>home/latestnew", {  page: page })
        .done(function( data ) {
            $("#pag_data").html( data );
    });
```

Use

```
   $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: <?php echo base_url();?>+"home/latestnew", 
         data: {  page: page },
         dataType: "json",

         cache:false,
         success: 
              function(data){
                alert(data);  //as a debugging message
                   $("#pag_data").html( data );
              }
          });// you have missed this bracket
```

it work for me.verify url in bowser .

Answer (score 0):

Few things that need to take care (May not necessary solve your issue):

1. Use site_url() instead of base_url() for creating paths. Like: site_url('controller_name/action_name/parameter_1');
   Use base_url() for loading assets like images, css, js etc
2. Get rid of canonical URLs or manage them properly else they may effect your site's SEO in wrong way.
   http://www.hyperarts.com/blog/www-vs-non-www-for-your-canonical-domain-url-which-is-best-and-why/

Answer (score 0):

`example.com` and `www.example.com` are different sites, which happen to have identical content on them.

Your server thinks that `example.com` is the real site so when you say:

```
"<?php echo base_url();?>home/latestnew"
```

the PHP outputs:

```
"http://example.com/home/latestnew"
```

Now if the browser is on `www.example.com`, it sees that URL and thinks that you are using Ajax to make a cross-origin request. This is [restricted by the same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).

---

The **best** thing you can do to deal with this is to **not host duplicate sites on different hostnames**. Reconfigure your server so that, instead of serving up the website when you request `www.example.com` it instead gives a 301 Redirect to `example.com`.

The *quick* thing you can do is to make sure you always use a URL on the *same site*. Change:

```
 "<?php echo base_url();?>home/latestnew"
```

to

```
"/home/latestnew"
```

so it is a relative URL.